# Rep. Loss for Downvoting spam

Tags: discussion, support

There was an **answer** to [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/11741/my-ambient-lighting-is-not-working-correctly) that was blaitent advertizing, and as many other people, I downvoted it *and* flagged it.

When this '**answer**' is deleted will the rep from the downvotes be restored? Are we meant to downvote these answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Downvotes on questions no longer cost the casting user 1 reputation, so they are effectively “free”.

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/

Downvoting these answers is certainly a good idea to make sure they stay at the bottom until we (the moderators) get a chance to see the flag and delete the answer. Whether you downvote or not, make sure to flag it so that we are made aware of it.

Comment: I know, the question was about the __answer__ that was downvoted. Is the rep restored when the moderator removes it?

Comment: Ah. In that case, I'm not certain but see [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2632/reedem-reputation-for-deleted-negative-answers/2638#2638) which indicates that the rep **is** restored when the answer is deleted (and the answer is written by a SO moderator).

Comment: Oki doki, thanks.

Comment: According to that answer, rep is restored upon the next rep-recalc, not when the answer is deleted.